# How to parse Java code to store it in a notation in some format

Tags: java, parsing, data-structures, abstract-syntax-tree

I am working on a research project in which I have to parse large java files and have to extract component notations out of the code. The components are dependent on java expressions and conditions.

So far the only option I can see is AST tree but it seems to be very complex. Can I extract or re write java code using AST plug in to store the code in a way that can map to components later?

What other options are there to parse java and make the rule base to store the info in some format?

I have explored Java cc, but its purpose seems to define a language. What I want to do is to extract something in component notation rather than defining a language. Still I need to define rules of extraction some how. How should I proceed?

Comment: If [the Java grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4) is more complex than you wish it were... Isn't that just a reality you'll have to accept if you want to parse Java code?

Comment: the first thing i am looking for is how to do it, mean what library, tool etc is best for the job, difficulty is the next thing, for time being it could be any thing but my focus is on conditional expressions and decision chunks like looping etc.

Comment: What information exactly do you need to get hold of? There may be different options, depending on what you plan to do (e.g. reading the class files and using reflection),

Comment: @ stefan for example lets say I want to parse code and depending on my rules of function calling I have to decide which function should be service of a component c1 and when c1 should finish off and c2 should start so its about defining components and their services or converting java code into components on basis of an assignment algorithm

Comment: https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser looks like your best bet for a library to parse Java.

Comment: @Alex can i use it in any plugin project, simple java project? or just maven based projects?

Comment: Maven is a good way to organise your dependencies. You should consider using it rather than manually managing jars. Nevertheless a project being on Maven Central means it's publicly available for all kinds of use. With a bit of googling you can easily find the jar. I'd link you but it depends on what version of Java you're using.

Comment: unfortunately I am not using maven right now, if i find the jar and import, is it all i have to do? any link for jar please

Comment: If you need to parse real Java code, you need a serious Java parser.  (Maybe the github thingie is).  But usually you need to be able to understand the meaning the symbols, too, and that is way beyond what a mere parser can do  (See my essay on "Life After Parsing"; check my bio), and is much harder to implement than a parser. If you think just ASTs are complex, then you are likely to find ASTs plus symbol tables (esp. if you include generics) really complex.   Then you still have to generate your extracted output.  You should consider a program transformation system with a Java front end.

Comment: @Baxter thank u fro some insight very helpful, pardon for dumb questions but I am new to such kind of work. my thinking is that all i need is AST cause i can re write the java code by only selecting the chunks I want and how I want to narrate them, am i right? Do i have to use a parser like GCC abd then have to map the output to AST? what is the combination of tools? can i do it with just AST re writing? where I will define the rules that how to tackle certain statement?

Comment: A parser and an AST won't cut it for the kind of work you appear to want to do. (See http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html). In general what you want is a Program Transformation (PTS) System http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation  In practice, you want a PTS that has seen trial by fire on tough projects; my tool DMS has that track record, (and a Java Front End) and while I know of other tools, they aren't as strong as DMS (IMHO but I've spent 20 years trying to make it strong).

Comment: Of the other tools I know about, the one that looks fairly good for Java is Jackpot:  http://mohsenvakilian.wordpress.com/2008/03/16/jackpot-rule-language/  I don't know its present status.   You can arguably use the JavaC compiler's internals but I have little knowledge of that, and I think it only offers raw access to the AST and type information, everthing else you have to code maually (e.g., unlike DMS and Jackpot, "no patterns" or "rewrites").

Comment: @Baxter I had a look at DMS web, what tools from the list do I need to input the java source files and then after extracting AST manipulate AST's to get code transformation of my wish

Comment: (Use @Ira Baxter if you want me to see your responses).  You need DMS and its Java Front End.  Further discussion should probably be with the company.